# What kind of rock is this?

Tags: geology, mineralogy, rocks, radioactivity

A few years ago in Venezuela, parque nacional de Cainama, the tourist guide found and gave me this rocks, he told us that a geologist told him that those could be radioactive but no one believed him. Nowadays I'm very curious of what kind of rock it may be.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site. Unfortunatelly, we are no longer suporting id-my-rock questions. I can sugest you [this site](https://www.thenakedscientists.com/forum/index.php?board=15.0) to ask. We wrote [this guide](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/a/125/20559) if it helps you to ask propertly.